# metallb and Helm traefik install dashbord 404 not found

Tags: kubernetes, traefik

I installted traefik using helm

but when I try to navigate trough web ui I have error 404 not found with http and https:

```
    helm install traefik traefik/traefik 

    kubectl get svc -l app.kubernetes.io/name=traefik
    NAME      TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
    traefik   LoadBalancer   10.99.97.18   10.0.2.13     80:32644/TCP,443:32704/TCP   17m

curl http://10.0.2.13
404 page not found
```

I have gitlab-ci in loadbalancer and it's working fine.

```
  kubectl get svc
    NAME                    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                        AGE
    kubernetes              ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                        4d23h
    load-balancer-service   LoadBalancer   10.106.191.82   10.0.2.10     80:31560/TCP                   3d3h
    test-gitlab             LoadBalancer   10.111.57.85    10.0.2.12     8080:31920/TCP,443:31004/TCP   2d6h
    traefik                 LoadBalancer   10.99.97.18     10.0.2.13     80:32644/TCP,443:32704/TCP     18m


curl http://10.0.2.12:8080
<html><body>You are being <a href="http://10.0.2.12:8080/users/sign_in">redirected</a>.</body></html>rbo@k8smaster1:~/metallb/nginx$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from [Traefik documentation](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/getting-started/install-traefik/#exposing-the-traefik-dashboard):

> This HelmChart does not expose the Traefik dashboard by default, for security concerns. Thus, there are multiple ways to expose the dashboard. For instance, the dashboard access could be achieved through a port-forward:

```
kubectl port-forward $(kubectl get pods --selector "app.kubernetes.io/name=traefik" --output=name) 9000:9000
```

> It can then be reached at: http://127.0.0.1:9000/dashboard/

Comment: yes thx I just saw that few hours after posting thx. Should I close/delete the post or publish all the way to expose service in Answer ?